# Android Studio: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Client not ready yet

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, adb

Every time I try to run my app on my phone I get **this message**

[image]

and it crashes. I don't know how to fix it, I already unchecked Instant Run and installed ADB Idea but still no luck. Any help?

EDIT (build.gradle):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fretshot.ihc.sapp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resValue "string", "google_maps_key", (project.findProperty("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") ?: "")
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.ncorti:slidetoact:0.3.0'
}
```

Comment: are you running on Huawei device or on different device have u tested

Comment: Yes I'm using a Huawei device since it's the only one I have to test my apps. But I've never had trouble with it until now.

Comment: Can you paste your build.gradle dependencies?

Comment: So there may be 2 reason for it your `device is not connected properly` or your device already having the application installed in it for `other user` so you need to uninstall for all users from your mobile

Comment: @lidkxx Pasted.

Comment: @DanielMtz ok, thought you may be trying to use play-services dependency in a too broad scope, but your build.gradle seems fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you *export* your launcher activity in AndroidManifest.xml? Seeing you're launching it via adb you need to add:

```
<activity
    android:name=".yourpackagename.YourActivity"
    android:exported="true"/>
```

in order for your activity to be adb-launchable. Activities with intent-filter are exported by default.

Comment: I did it but I still get the same error as before.


https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTPhc.jpg

Comment: How would exporting the activity resolve this issue?